# Бинпоиск с условием

Tags: c++

Мне надо уменьшить сложность программы, я хочу вот такой кусок кода (m - отсортированный вектор) :

```
int j = i - 1;
while (j >= 0 && m[i] - m[j] < k) {
    --j;
}
```

заменить на бинпоиск, как реализовать бинпоиск с таким хитрым условием?

Comment: Изначально `i` больше или меньше `j` ?

Comment: `i`  вообще фиксированно?

Comment: Как минимум m[i] у вас не меняется. Значит m[j] >= m[i]-k. Можно получить m[i]-k как константу и проверять условие с ней. но вектор я так понимаю все равно может работать только перебором. В идеале можно было бы идти делением пополам

Comment: @newman,  добавил условие

Comment: @YuriyOrlov, i фиксированно во время работы while

Comment: Идеи можете посмотреть [здесь](http://pastebin.com/kv45jnVg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сама функция бин.поиска - int fast(vector m, int i, int k), возвращает позицию.
Тут ещё встроено тестирование на случайно сгенерированных данных и сравнение с "тупой" реализацией

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <assert.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int r(int lt, int rt)
{
    return rand() % (rt - lt + 1) + lt;
}

bool good(vector<int> m, int i, int k, int j)
{
    return !(j >= 0 && m[i] - m[j] < k);
}

int slow(vector<int> m, int i, int k)
{
    int j = i - 1;
    while (!good(m, i, k, j)) {
        --j;
    }
    return j;
}

int fast(vector<int> m, int i, int k)
{
    int lt = 0;
    int rt = i - 1;

    if (!good(m, i, k, lt))
        return -1;
    if (good(m, i, k, rt))
        return rt;

    while (rt - lt > 1) 
    {
        int mid = (lt + rt) / 2;
        if (good(m, i, k, mid))
            lt = mid;
        else
            rt = mid;
    }
    return lt;
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    vector<int> m(r(2, 70));
    for(int i = 0; i < (int) m.size(); i++)
        m[i] = r(0, 99);
    sort(m.begin(), m.end());
    int i = r(1, m.size() - 1);
    int k = 50;
    for (int tt = 0;; tt++)
    {
        cout << tt;
        assert(slow(m, i, k) == fast(m, i, k));
        cout << " OK" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Бинарный поиск - это `lower_bound`:

```
auto i_it = begin(m) + i;
auto j_it = std::lower_bound(begin(m), i_it, *i_it - k);
int j = j_it - begin(m);
```

Или если нужен именно последний элемент из равных - то надо использовать `upper_bound`:

```
auto j_next_it = std::upper_bound(begin(m), i_it, *i_it - k);
if (j_next_it != begin(m)) --j_next_it;
int j = j_it - begin(m);
```

Comment: Отличный ответ, не пойму, почему все реализуют двоичный поиск вручную.

Comment: (А почему `std::upper_bound`, но не `std::begin`?)

Comment: @VladD, может, потому что студенты?

Comment: @Abyx, неправильно работает почему-то, делаю точно так же как у вас

Comment: @ixSci: Ну это да :) И им это рассказывали на последней лекции.

Comment: @Abyx: Ого, не знал. То есть про ADL я, конечно, знал, но не видел практического применения. Спасибо!

Comment: @Abyx, вот http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499227/

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я понял нужно что-то вроде такого?

```
int bin_search(std::vector<int> a, size_t pos, int value)
{
    size_t left = 0;
    size_t right = pos;
    size_t pivot;
    while (left < right)
    {
        pivot = (right + left) / 2;
        if (a[pivot] < value)
        {
            if (left == pivot)
                break;
            left = pivot;
        }
        else
        {
             right = pivot;
        }
    }
    return a[pivot];
}
// ...
int value = bin_search(a, i - 1, a[i] - k);
```