# Использование lower/upper_bound

Tags: c++

В вопросе [Бинпоиск с условием](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498814/%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D1%81-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/498853#498853) мне нужно было заменить вот такой цикл:

```
int j = i - 1; // i пробегает значения от 1 до n в цикле снаружи
while (j >= 0 && v1[i] - v1[j] < n2) { // v1 - отсортированный вектор, m фиксировано
    --j;
}
```

на более быструю версию. Мне подсказали, что можно использовать lower_bound/upper_bound вот так:

> Бинарный поиск - это `lower_bound`:
>
> ```
> auto i_it = begin(v1) + i;
> auto j_it = std::lower_bound(begin(v1), i_it, *i_it - n2);
> int j = j_it - begin(v1);
> ```
>
> Или если нужен именно последний элемент из равных - то надо
>   использовать `upper_bound`:
>
> ```
> auto j_next_it = std::upper_bound(begin(v1), i_it, *i_it - n2);
> if (j_next_it != begin(v1)) --j_next_it;
> int j = j_it - begin(v1);
> ```

---

Исходный вариант кода (со старым циклом)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int n1; // длина вектора
    unsigned int n2; // параметр для цикла
    std::cin >> n1 >> n2;
    if (n1 == 0) {
        std::cout << "0";
        return 0;
    }
    std::vector<unsigned int> v1(n1);
    for (size_t i = 0; i != n1; ++i) {
        std::cin >> v1[i]; // считываювектор
    }
    std::vector<unsigned int> v2(n1);
    for (size_t i = 0; i != n1; ++i) {
        std::cin >> v2[i];
    }
    std::vector<unsigned long long> ans(n1, 0);
    ans[0] = v2[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n1; i++) {
        int j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && v1[i] - v1[j] < n2) { // вот этот цикл
            --j;
        } 
        if (j < 0) {
            ans[i] = v2[i] > ans[i - 1] ? v2[i] : ans[i - 1];
        } else if (ans[j] + v2[i] >= ans[i - 1]) {
            ans[i] = ans[j] + v2[i];
        } else {
            ans[i] = ans[i - 1];
        }
    }
    std::cout << ans[n1 - 1];
    return 0;
}
```

---

Я пробовал заменить (здесь второй вариант из ответа, но первый я тоже пробовал и тоже не работает): вот программа

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int n1;
    unsigned int n2;
    std::cin >> n1 >> n2;
    if (n1 == 0) {
        std::cout << "0";
        return 0;
    }
    std::vector<unsigned int> v1(n1);
    for (size_t i = 0; i != n1; ++i) {
        std::cin >> v1[i];
    }
    std::vector<unsigned int> v2(n1);
    for (size_t i = 0; i != n1; ++i) {
        std::cin >> v2[i];
    }
    std::vector<unsigned long long> ans(n1, 0);
    ans[0] = v2[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n1; i++) {
        auto i_it = begin(v1) + i; // вот здесь был тот цикл
        auto j_next_it = std::upper_bound(begin(v1), i_it, *i_it - n2);
        if (j_next_it != begin(v1)) --j_next_it;
        int j = j_next_it - begin(v1);
        if (j < 0) {
            ans[i] = v2[i] > ans[i - 1] ? v2[i] : ans[i - 1];
        } else if (ans[j] + v2[i] >= ans[i - 1]) {
            ans[i] = ans[j] + v2[i];
        } else {
            ans[i] = ans[i - 1];
        }
    }
    std::cout << ans[n1 - 1];
    return 0;
}
```

И Lower и Upper bound'ы работают не так как цикл
(пример входа)

```
4 10
5 10 15 20
100 50 100 300
```

Вывод при использовании цикла - 400, а при использовании upper_bound - 450

Comment: @Abyx, задал вопрос с кодом, где использую

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите полные версии обоих вариантов функции. И еще не понятно во входных данных что где: если 4 и 10 это длины векторов, то в третьей строке должно быть не 4, а 10 элементов. И в коде не помешали бы коментарии о том что вы делаете.

Comment: Замечания по входным данным снимаются - не внимательно прочитал код.

Comment: @Cerbo, привел обе версии

Comment: ветка `j < 0` лишняя

Comment: @Cerbo, при исходном способе нахождения j, он может быть равен -1, это отдельный случай, ветка не лишняя

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала упростим исходный код:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    unsigned k = 10;
    std::vector<unsigned> v1 = {5, 10, 15, 20};
    std::vector<unsigned> v2 = {100, 50, 100, 300};
    std::vector<unsigned long long> ans(v1.size());
    ans[0] = v2[0];
    for (auto i = 1u; i != ans.size(); ++i) {
        int j = i; while (j != 0 && v1[j - 1] > v1[i] - k) --j;
        auto t = (j != 0) ? ans[j - 1] : 0;
        ans[i] = std::max(ans[i - 1], t + v2[i]);
    }
    std::cout << ans.back();
}
```

Теперь `j` это индекс элемента, следующего за нужным, т.е. как раз то, что возвращает `upper_bound`. Значит можно написать

```
auto j = std::upper_bound(begin(v1), begin(v1) + i, v1[i] - k) - begin(v1);
```

Также вместо индексов можно использовать итераторы:

```
int main() {
    unsigned k = 10;
    std::vector<unsigned> v1 = {5, 10, 15, 20};
    std::vector<unsigned> v2 = {100, 50, 100, 300};
    std::vector<unsigned long long> ans;
    unsigned long long current = 0;
    for (auto it1 = begin(v1), it2 = begin(v2); it1 != end(v1); ++it1, ++it2) {
        auto j = std::upper_bound(begin(v1), it1, *it1 - k) - begin(v1);
        auto t = (j != 0) ? ans[j - 1] : 0;
        current = std::max(current, t + *it2);
        ans.push_back(current);
    }
    std::cout << ans.back();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

На первый взгляд, отличие кода:

```
    auto i_it = begin(v1) + i; // вот здесь был тот цикл
    auto j_next_it = std::upper_bound(begin(v1), i_it, *i_it - n2);
```

от "того цикла":

```
int j = i - 1; // i пробегает значения от 1 до n в цикле снаружи
while (j >= 0 && v1[i] - v1[j] < n2) { // m - отсортированный вектор, k фиксировано
    --j;
}
```

в том, что правая граница в линейном поиске это `i - 1`, а в двоичном итератор соответствует `i`-му элементу.

Соответственно надо написать

```
auto i_it = begin(v1) + i - 1;
```

Comment: тогда например на таком работать не будет 5 15 //
2 14 25 31 37 //
8 19 20 11 25. Ответ должен быть 44.

Comment: @Parket, откровенно говоря я даже не пытался разбираться, что именно Вы считаете. В самом деле думаете, что кому-то интересно восстанавливать задачу по коду? Если хотите реальной помощи, то толком опишите постановку задачи. Вообще же можно просто попечатать, какие индексы находит двоичный поиск, и если это не то, что Вам нужно, то разбираться почему (в правильности же самого upper/lower_bound я не сомневаюсь)

Comment: @avp Так топикастер уже создает с этой задачей третий (а может и того больше) вопрос. И у него есть код. Но, в том то и дело, что он не желает искать в дебагере ошибку. Он снова и снова пытается переписать код, а не понять, почему он не работает при разных условиях. Похоже, что у него задача не мытьем, так катаньем заставить других решить задачу.

Answer (score 1):

В варианте с циклом переменная `j` принимает значения {-1,-1,0}, потому что разница между соседними элементами `v1 = {5,10,15,20}` всегда равна 5.

А вот варианте с `std::upper_bound` переменная `j` принимает значения {0,0,1}. Результаты приведу в таблице:

```
 i | ищем | находим | j
-------------------------
 1     0       5      0
 2     5      10      0
 3    10      15      1
```